# Format: add trailing spaces to character output to left-justify

Tags: fortran, string-formatting, fortran90

How do you format a string to have constant width *and* be left-justified? There is the `Aw` formatter, where `w` denotes desired width of character output, but it prepends the spaces if `w > len(characters)`, instead of appending them.

When I try

```
44 format(A15)
   print 44, 'Hi Stack Overflow'
```

I get

```
>        Hi Stack Overflow<
```

instead of

```
>Hi Stack Overflow        <
```

Is there any simple Fortran formatting solution that solves this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As noted in the question, the problem is that when a character expression of length shorter than the output field width the padding spaces appear *before* the character expression.  What we want is for the padding spaces to come after our desired string.

There isn't a simple *formatting* solution, in the sense of a natural edit descriptor.  However, what we can do is output an expression with sufficient trailing spaces (which count towards the length).

For example:

```
print '(A50)', 'Hello'//REPEAT(' ',50)
```

or

```
character(50) :: hello='Hello'
print '(A50)', hello
```

or even

```
print '(A50)', [character(50) :: 'hello']
```

That is, in each case the output item is a character of length (at least) 50.  Each will be padded on the right with blanks.

If you chose, you could even make a function which returns the extended (left-justified) expression:

```
print '(A50)', right_pad('Hello')
```

where the function is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Not pretty, but it gets the job done. Thanks! (Definitely laughed @ 'the function is left as an exercise for the reader.')

Answer (score 4):

To complete @francescalus excellent answer for future reference, the proposed solution also works in case of allocatables in place of string literals:

```
character(len=:), allocatable :: a_str

a_str = "foobar"

write (*,"(A,I4)") a_str, 42
write (*,"(A,I4)") [character(len=20) :: a_str], 42
```

will output

```
foobar  42
foobar                42
```

Answer (score 1):

a bit ugly but you can concatenate a blank string:

```
    character*15 :: blank=' '
    print 44, 'Hi Stack Overflow'//blank
```

Comment: Could even just be `character*15 :: blank=''`.

Answer (score 1):

```
program test ! Write left justified constant width character columns 
! declare some strings.
character(len=32) :: str1,str2,str3,str4,str5,str6 
! define the string values.
str1 = "     Nina "; str2 = "       Alba  " ; str3 = "        blue   " 
str4 = "  Jamil   "; str5 = "   Arnost "    ; str6 = " green             "
write(*,'(a)') "123456789012345678901234567890"
! format to 3 columns 10 character wide each.
! and adjust the stings to the left.
write(*,'(3(a10))') adjustl(str1), adjustl(str2), adjustl(str3) 
write(*,'(3(a10))') adjustl(str4), adjustl(str5), adjustl(str6) 
end program test
```

```
 $ ./a.out
123456789012345678901234567890
Nina      Alba      blue 
Jamil     Arnost    green
```

`adjustl()` moves leading spaces to the end of the string.

Comment: This suffers from the same problem as the asker wishes to solve: `write(*,'(A99)') trim( adjustl(string) )` still has lots of leading blanks.

Comment: @ francescalus, I agree, Thank You for pointing this out. The ask is "How do you format a string to have *constant width* and be left-justified" .  I have modified the example accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you do not limit the number of output characters.

Change it to the following will work:

```
44 format(A)
 print 44, 'Hi Stack Overflow'
```

Comment: Please explain your solution in detail so that others will understand more easily

Comment: How does this justify the text as desired within a field of requested width?

Comment: The Ann format is used to confine the output character variable in the specific length. If your varible length is not sure or in a "free format" , just format(A) is enough.